# Get notified when instance of app widget was added to homescreen by user

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-emulator, android-widget

I've developed an android app where you can customize your own widget.

My problem: I want to start an `Intent` when an instance of the widget is added to the homescreen.

Until now I'm using the `onReceive()` method, which is called by the system in my `AppWidgetProvider` class as soon as anything happens. There I wait for an `Intent` which is sent by the system and which has the intent action 
    `AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_OPTIONS_CHANGED`

(`onWidgetDataOptionsChanged()` is according to android developer page the right method: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html).

I've tried this on several real devices and it always works. But on all emulators with new android versions, no `Intent` with the above mentioned action is sent by the system when I add a widget instance to my homescreen.

So, is the issue caused by the emulators or should I wait for another kind of action?